# In Android, can the user grant an app permission to view their current webpage?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-browser

I'm hoping to write an app that is overlayed on the user's web browser (ideally I want the app to work on all web browsers - but if not, just working on the major web browsers: firefox, chrome, and the default browser is fine), so they can access the app's functionality whenever they are browsing (similar to how facebook's "chatheads" are drawn over the current app the user is using). However, in order for the app to work, it must be able to access the current URL the user is browsing/the html document of the web page. Is it possible for the user to grant permission to my app, so it can access the html/url of the current webpage the user is browsing?